# Error con XMLHttpRequest y HTTPS

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, url

en mi petición a la API REST, he de decir que estoy en un modulo de wordpress metiendo javascript

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 }
           ;

           xhttp.open("POST", "intranet.tal-tal.com/api/public/api/project", true);
           xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           xhttp.send("name="+name+"&surname="+surname+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone
           +"&address="+address+"&city="+city+"&province="+province
           +"&message="+message+"&business_type="+business_type+"&meters_establishment="+meters_establishment+"&price="+price);
 }
```

Y mi problema es que cuando lanzo esa petición me hace la petición a :

```
https://tal-tal.com/contacto/intranet.tal-tal.com/api/public/api/project
```

cuando deberia de hacermela directamente a

```
https://intranet.tal-tal.com/api/public...
```

No sé si será un problema con la escapada de caracteres pero no lo entiendo, si le pongo https:// tampoco va pero si le pongo https: sin las // me lo coge pero sigue mandandome a /contacto/intranet.tal-tal.com..

Alguna idea ??

Tambien he de decir que si pongo 
http:intranet.tal-tal.com/disenaAPI/public/api/project
si que me lo coge pero no me interesa http, si pongo la s ya no me lo coge

Comment: ¿y esto qué tiene que ver con Laravel?

Comment: Imagino que por que estoy atacando a una api rest, no se si tendrá algo que ver por eso lo pregunto

Comment: Un API no implica el uso de Laravel, a menos que el API esté hecha en dicho framework.

Comment: Si pongo laravel será por que esta echa con ese framework no? no se pregunto

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el error que te da cuando pones el https?

Comment: Podes agregar info sobre la configuración de la red. Que es intranet.tal-tal.com? y que diferencia tiene con tal-tal.com. Si haces ping a uno y a otro te devuelve el resultado esperado? Si estás en windows limpiaste la cache de dns (ipconfig /flushdns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces una llamada AJAX tienes 3 opciones:

1. Poner la ruta **completa**, incluyendo el protocolo: `'https://intranet.tal-tal.com/api/public'`.
2. Poner la ruta **absoluta**, omitiendo protocolo y dominio (que serán los que hay en la barra de navegación) y comenzando por `'/'`: si en la barra de tu navegador aparece `https://tal-tal.com/contacto/`, una llamada a `'/api/public'` se entenderá como:

   ```
   https://tal-tal.com/api/public
   ```
3. Poner la ruta **relativa** a la URL de la página actual: si en la barra de tu navegador aparece `https://tal-tal.com/contacto/`, una llamada a `'loquesea.com/api/'` se entenderá como la concatenación de ambas:

   ```
   https://tal-tal.com/contacto/loquesea.com/api/
   ```

En tu caso has omitido el protocolo, pero has dejado el dominio, con lo que estamos en el caso 3 y el navegador ha concatenado la dirección que ves en la barra con la URL que has puesto en la petición